# Symfony 2.7 routing error?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm studying Symfony2 making test program. I met some errors about symfony routing error. The error is:

```
Class AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController does not exist in C:\projects\classic-symfony\src\AppBundle/Controller/
```

(which is being imported from `"C:\projects\classic-symfony\app/config\routing.yml"`).

Certainly I deleted , so 2 lines are written, `DefaultController.php` in `C:\projects\classic-symfony\src\AppBundle/Controller/`, and deployed `ToppageController.php` instead of it.

`ToppageController.php` is very simple and the following,

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ToppageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->rendor('Toppage/index.html.twig');    
    }
}
```

Why does this code not work ? This is routing problem ?

---

4.23.2016
Thank you everyone. I'm out of office so will try and response next week.

---

4.25.2016
I replied new problem to this reply. Could you help this problem ?

Comment: return $this->render instead of this->rendor

Comment: You may have removed (changed) the `DefaultController`, but it's probably stilled *wired* to the application in `app/config/routing.yml`. Check that file for it's contents. Then check the [manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#including-external-routing-resources).

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: It seems to refer annotation in app/config/routing.yml. I will reply to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete your `route` to this controller from `app/config/routing.yml`.

After that don't forget to clear the cache. In `dev` environment you can just run:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

In `prod` environment you need to add parameter:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply.

I wrote app/config/routing.yml to the following,

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

This seems to refer the source code annotation in AppBundle/Controller/.
I tried to run

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

But the following is shown on console,

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
Class AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController does not exist in C:\projects\classic-symfony\src\AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from "C:\projects\classic-symfony\app/config\routing.yml").

[ReflectionException]
Class AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController does not exist
```

This means it can not clear the cache ?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue now too - not sure I get it - from what I've read this bit of confioguration should allow Controllers to bbe organized in any sub-directory under that given bundle (running S3.2.1???)

Answer (score 0):

Search for AppBundle in your directory and look for instances where App Bundle is still being referred. Get rid of those instances which may be in routing.yml / services.yml and then run
     php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod